# stage.swapChildren(MClip1, Mclip2); not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

i have made a drag and match game where i have a rectangle circle movieclip ..when rectangle/or circle hit a specific box rectangle will always be behind circle and circle will always be over retangle,if i drag rectangle first then  circle  its ok..but if i drag circle first then rectangle ..circle always takes its position behind ractengle i used stage.swapChildren(ccircle, crect) but its not working ...here is my code

```
 crect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown1);
function item_onMouseDown1(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        crect = MovieClip(event.target);
        startX1 = crect.x;
        startY1 = crect.y;
        crect.startDrag();
        setChildIndex(crect, this.numChildren-1);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp1);

    }
function stage_onMouseUp1(event:MouseEvent):void {

stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp1);
crect.stopDrag();

    if(crect.hitTestObject(box3))
    {
        TweenMax.to(crect, 0.5, {x:hit2X, y:hit2Y,height:height2Y, width:weight2X, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
         //crect.mouseEnabled=false;


    }
    else
    {
        TweenMax.to(crect, 0.5, {x:startX1, y:startY1, ease:Bounce.easeOut});

    }
}
ccircle.buttonMode=true;
ccircle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown1);

function onMouseDown1(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        ccircle = MovieClip(event.target);
        startX1 = ccircle.x;
        startY1 = ccircle.y;
        ccircle.startDrag();
        setChildIndex(ccircle, this.numChildren-1);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp1);

    }
function onMouseUp1(event:MouseEvent):void {

stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp1);
ccircle.stopDrag();

    if(ccircle.hitTestObject(box3))
    {
         TweenMax.to(ccircle, 0.5, {x:hit1X, y:hit1Y,height:height1Y, width:weight1X, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
        //stage.swapChildren(ccircle, crect);

        //setChildIndex(ccircle, this.numChildren-1);
         //ccircle.mouseEnabled=false;


    }
    else
    {
        TweenMax.to(ccircle, 0.5, {x:startX1, y:startY1, ease:Bounce.easeOut});

    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/stack here is the fla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change `ccircle` index to -1. Only 0, 1, 2, ...

`stage.setChildIndex(ccircle, -1);`

You should write:

```
if (getChildIndex(ccircle) < getChildIndex(crect))
    swapChildren(ccircle, crect);
```

It means: If `ccircle` is under `crect` then put `ccircle` on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
removeChild(crect);
addChild(crect);
```

That will always put `crect` on top. Of course if you need `ccircle` on top, do the same to it.

Comment: addChild(crect); does that just fine why would you need removeChild(crect); before that?

Answer (score 0):

i simply set setChildIndex(crect, this.numChildren-2);
and  setChildIndex(crect, this.numChildren-2); and its working perfect,because its not for setting circle on top only.while dragging i have to put dragged object on top of other objects..

Answer (score 0):

I also found some info you can read on
Gary Rosenzweig website that I been studying myself on the display list in flash.

The site is http://flashgameu.com/ and scroll down an look for "understanding the display list."

It explains swapping children by name and also by location in the display list.

Watching his pod cast will help you understand the options using the display list with swapping children, addChild,removeChild and childIndex.

Its also free and a good site with some information on how to do things with flash and as3 programming.